# Eclipse crashes after opensuse update and no error log

Tags: java, eclipse, opensuse

I did a fresh install of OpenSuse 13.3 (64) and downloaded eclipse kepler.

After a (short) while eclipse crashes. It seems to be triggered by using the arrow keys (who do not move the cursor).

I checked .metadata/ in my workspace, it does not contain an error message.

My system uses openjdk 1.7. Because of the error, I installed jdk and jre. I tried starting eclipse with -vm "location of jdk or jre", to no avail. Also added it to eclipse.ini

I also went to settings -> java -> jres and added the new jre.

All of this makes no difference. Is there anything else that I can check to see what is wrong? Or otherwise point me to an alternative of eclipse, because I need to work : )

Comment: I just added jdk to my path, perhaps that was important too.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same issue. Looking in other foruns i found this solution:

Run eclipse as "eclipse -vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla".

http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/492348-eclipse-juno-crashs-opensuse-13-1-a-3.html